# Singular and Plural "You" - how does one differentiate in Spanish between a singular and plural you?

Tags: traducción, formalidad, persona-gramatical

What is the most accurate "you all" translation?

There are two "yous". Singular and plural you. The latter is sometimes called "you all", "y'all", or "youse guys" in American English. What is the most accurate Spanish rendition of plural you?

I tried three online translators:

- Translate.com gives me "you all" (untranslated => it throws up its hands, apparently)
- Google Translate gives me "**todos ustedes**"
- Bing Translator gives me "**todos**"

In other words, how does one differentiate in Spanish between a singular and plural you?

> - You (Paco) gave me a black eye
> - You (Paco, Rubén, and Raúl) gave me a black eye

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spanish from Spain, there is the informal plural you ***vosotros***, and the formal plural you ***ustedes***.

Latinamerican Spanish, as far as I can tell, lost the informal one, leaving only ***ustedes***.

Spain-spanish informal would say:

> ¿Iréis vosotros al cine esta noche? <sub>Will you all (informal) go to the movies tonight?</sub>

Spain-spanish formal, Latinamerican formal/informal:

> ¿Irán ustedes al cine esta noche?

In both cases the pronoun can be omitted as it can be derived from the verb.

As for your friend Paco and the others...

> You (Paco) gave me a black eye
>     --> Me dejaste el ojo morado
>
> You (Paco, Ruben, and Raul) gave me a black eye:
>    --> Me dejasteis el ojo morado (informal Spain)
>     --> Me dejaron el ojo morado (all the others)

Comment: vos también existe en español ¬¬

Comment: Correcto, pero en España y Latinoamérica su significado en términos de formalidad son totalmente opuestos. Es España está  por arriba de usted, mientras que en latinoamérica es bien informal. Como español nunca tratarías a tu padre de vos.

Answer (score 3):

According to [StudySpanish](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/subpro.htm)

> When referring to "you-all," there are two choices in Spanish:
>
> ustedes / you-all formal
>
> vosotros / you-all familiar
>
> Once again, the difference lies in the degree of formality conveyed by the speaker. However, the vosotros form is used primarily in Spain. Throughout Latin America, "ustedes" is generally used in both formal and informal situations to refer to "you-all."
>
> Speaking to a group of children (in Spain): vosotros
>
> Speaking to a group of children (in Latin America): ustedes
>
> Speaking to a group of strangers  (in Spain): ustedes
>
> Speaking to a group of strangers  (in Latin America): ustedes

About your examples  *You (Paco) gave me a black eye* and *You (Paco, Ruben, and Raul) gave me a black eye*, we would distinghish:

Singular subject ? Then use *tú/usted*:

> Tú me dejaste el ojo morado / Usted me dejó el ojo morado.

Plural subject? Then use *vosotros/ustedes*:

> Vosotros me dejasteis el ojo morado / Ustedes me dejaron el ojo morado.